new pycharm installation (on windows) doesnt show anything on menu
A new pycharm installation (on windows) doesnt show anything on menu option:new->python package
activity monitor or logs doesnt show anything
any sugestion ? what could be the reason to happen ?
i already:

try to use on a custom project
upgrade pip,setuptools,wheel
change environment
change interpreter
miniconda installation
made a new installation
ask to jetbrains (ask for license and log information)

environment

PyCharm 2024.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-243.21565.199, built on November 13, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.5+8-b631.16 amd64 (JCEF 122.1.9)
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1500M
Cores: 4
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true


Could you attach a screenshot?

This issue typically happens due to PyCharm misconfiguration or missing dependencies. Here's how to troubleshoot:
1. Check File Structure
Ensure you're in a project folder and not just an empty workspace. PyCharm only allows creating Python packages inside projects.
2. Configure Python Interpreter

Go to File > Settings > Project: <Your Project> > Python Interpreter.
Add and configure a valid Python interpreter.

3. Enable Project View

Ensure you're in Project View (View > Tool Windows > Project).
Right-click on a folder in the project directory, and try New > Python Package.

4. Invalidate Caches and Restart

Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart.

5. Update PyCharm
Ensure you're using the latest PyCharm version (Help > Check for Updates).
If the issue persists, reinstall PyCharm.

thkx it seems Cache was the problem, however i also delete .idea folder
